# I'm trying to split my string with multiple symbols in split() method but it's not working

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to split my regex but it's not splitting for some reason. Here's my code

```
String str = "sdef@srdfsrd[es[edf@edfv";
String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\\@\\["); 
for (String a : arrOfStr) 
{
  System.out.println(a);
}
```

output:

```
sdef@srdfsrd[es[edf@edfv
```

expected output:

```
sdef
srdfsrd
es
edf
edfv
```

The same problem for:

```
String[] arrOfStr = str.split(",:");  //not splitting the word at all
```

Answer (score 4):

`"\\@\\["` matches `@[`, which is **not** in your string. Change your RegEx to `"[@\\[]"`, which is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - that means it will split on either `@` or `[`.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/A8W2RB/1) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `"@|\\[` instead of `\\@\\[`

Note that in regex pattern, `|` works as `OR` i.e. by using `"@|\\[` you are instructing the code to split the given string either on `@` `OR` on `[`

Alternatively, you can use `[@\\[]` where `[]` specifies the [character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "sdef@srdfsrd[es[edf@edfv";
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("@|\\[");
        for (String a : arrOfStr) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
sdef
srdfsrd
es
edf
edfv
```